# Ошибка в перегрузке потоков

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Код программы: [на дропбоксе](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3973519/mnogestvo-1.06.cpp)

Перегружены потоки ввода и вывода, но видимо не правильно. Подскажите в чем проблема и как это исправить.

**Добавлено.**

Компилятор пишет о наличии посторонних символов, насколько я понял.

> `set.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char=""> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char=""> > &,class set<int> &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@AAV?$set@H@@@Z)`

Comment: А что пишет компилятор?

Comment: пишет о наличии посторонних символов, насколько я понял.
set.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char=""> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char=""> > &,class set<int> &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@AAV?$set@H@@@Z)

Comment: Похоже у вас стандартная библиотека C++ не прилинкована. Вы меняли что-нибудь в настройках проекта?

Comment: У меня этот код не то что не линкуется, а даже не компилируется. Каким компилятором пытаемся скомпилировать? (я - gcc 4.6)

Comment: Сделайте операторами инлайновыми (встроенными). А еще поищите по ХэшКоду - аналогичная проблема уже встрчалась

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вынесенные операции из шаблонов нужно явно помечать как `inline`, иначе возникают такие же проблемы, как, например, если помещать код **просто** функций в `header-`файлы. Почему в таком случае появляются ошибки множественного определения, достаточно очевидно.

---

Вообще, считается стандартом де-факто писать все функции шаблонных классов прямо в теле класса, т.е как будто бы они все были автоматически помечены как `inline`. Так делают в `boost`, `Qt` и других солидных проектах и не вижу смысла пытаться делать как-то иначе.

---

### **Update**:

---

Извините, первая версия ответа была *"не особо глядя".* Т.е, она описывает проблему, которая тоже присутствует в вашем коде *(см. ссылку про инлайны)*, но к компилируемости и линкованию она отношения не имеет.

В случае, если бы это влияло на компилируемость, то ошибка в `MSVS` была бы в духе `multiple definition of X`.

Возвращаясь к вопросу, стандарт `C++` *(да и здравый смысл, в общем-то, тоже)* говорит, что  в вашем случае необходимо помечать тип шаблона для дружественных операторов, т.е, если конкретно:

```
template <class tm> friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &out, mnogestvo<tm> &ob);
template <class tm> friend istream & operator >>(istream &in, mnogestvo<tm> &ob);
```

*Могу дать более развернутые референсы, объясняющие причины и необходимость в этом, если вам интересно.*

Comment: можно пример кода inline?

Comment: @Сергей Пример кода инлайн - `template <class tm>
inline ostream & operator << (ostream &out,mnogestvo<tm> &ob)`